# How to copy a file to another directory programmatically?

Tags: android

There is an `image file` inside a `directory`. How to `copy` this `image file` into another `directory` that was just created ? The two `directories` are on the same `internal storage` of the device :)

Comment: With code or generally?

Comment: programmatically , with code :)

Comment: I gave you ny recursion functions. It allows copy of single file or a whole directory and all of it's childer. Cheers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use these functions. The first one will copy whole directory with all children or a single file if you pass in a file. The second one is only usefull for files and is called for each file in the first one.

Also note you need to have permissions to do that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Functions:

```
 public static void copyFileOrDirectory(String srcDir, String dstDir) {

        try {
            File src = new File(srcDir);
            File dst = new File(dstDir, src.getName());

            if (src.isDirectory()) {

                String files[] = src.list();
                int filesLength = files.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                    String src1 = (new File(src, files[i]).getPath());
                    String dst1 = dst.getPath();
                    copyFileOrDirectory(src1, dst1);

                }
            } else {
                copyFile(src, dst);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        if (!destFile.getParentFile().exists())
            destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to get progress of it?

Comment: you can't with this implementation because you don't know how many files are up in front nor their sizes... you would need to know this if you wanted the progress, which would ultimatly slow this down. If you want performance, screw progress.

Comment: You can use `try (FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel(); FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel())` to avoid using `finally`

Comment: The perfect solution.Wroked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to copy image programtically then use following code.

```
     File sourceLocation= new File (sourcepath);
     File targetLocation= new File (targetpath);

     InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

** Use FileUtils This Is Simple Fast And Best method and Download Jar file from here**

public void MoveFiles(String sourcepath) {

```
         File source_f = new File(sourcepath);
        
        String destinationPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/WhatsappStatus/yourfilename.mp4";
        File destination = new File(destinationPath);
        try
        {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source_f , destination);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[Go To Link For FileUtils Jar](https://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio24jar.htm)